# Toast message is not display in device using IONIC

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to display toast message in IONIC.  I am following this guide on how to [Show Native Toast Notifications Using Ionic Framework](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/09/show-native-toast-notifications-using-ionic-framework/)

I am getting the following error in Android Studio:

[image: Error message screenshot]

I do not know why I got this error.

Comment: can you make a codepen/plnkr ??

Comment: I am using android developer to run apk on device.  Because toast is not display in browser.  and also using same code as mention link.

Comment: yeah, that's right toast won't run in a browser ... I'm using the same toast provider and it runs without problems, just wanted to see if you are not missing something in your code.

Comment: This is codepen link : https://codepen.io/kantilalr/pen/VaQGOQ

Comment: how are you loading cordova.js ? in you codepen you got 404 for it so whole project suffer from dependencies injection

Answer (score 0):

Toast are you using to control the message?

```
.controller('SampleCtrl', function($http, $scope, $cordovaToast) {

  $cordovaToast
    .show('Message', 'long', 'bottom')
    .then(function(success) {
    }, function (error) {
      console.log("Toast message error : " + error);
    });

})
```